# Getting jQuery.ajax to play nice with my jsonp webservice

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp, jax-ws

I'm having difficulty getting `$.ajax` to work with my webservice.

I have a webservice I wrote in Java (and I suck at Java) which expects urls like `example.com/webservice/somestuff/callback`

and returns JSONP like `callback({"success":true})`

My jquery resembles:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", dataType: "jsonp",
    url: '//example.com/someStuff', 
}).done(doSomething)
```

The problem is, all the nice stuff jQuery does to make JSONP work is messing me up.  It appends a querystring (i.e. `?callback=jQuery19786...`), where my Service expects just a regular path parameter.

If I could somehow convince jQuery to do `example.com/webservice/somestuff/jQuery19786...` that would be ideal.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place `??` where you want the callback to be placed.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", dataType: "jsonp",
    url: '//example.com/someStuff/??', 
}).done(doSomething)
```

An alternative is to use the beforeSend option to manipulate the url after jQuery modifies it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "//example.com/foo/bar/?callback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR,options){        
        options.url = options.url.replace(/\?callback\=/,"");
        //console.log(options.url);
        //return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it :-(.  `//example.com/someStuff/??` is converted to `//example.com/someStuff?callback=...`

Comment: wait. I lied haha. Renegade semi-colon messed me up. This *does* appear to work. Though now I have a new problem...

Comment: which was fixed with a small `cache: true`

Comment: I found another way around it too, could use beforeSend to modify the url before it gets sent.